# Add snapshot.val & snapshot.key to an array while I´m subscribed

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, firebase

I´m gonna break my head with a stone ^^" 
I have this code:

```
            this.af.database.list('/Documentos', { preserveSnapshot: true })
            .subscribe(snapshots => {
                snapshots.forEach(snapshot => {
                    console.log(snapshot.key, snapshot.val());
                });
            })
```

With that I extract all the data correctly, but now I want to add to an object array or something like that (I started few weeks ago with Firebase + Angular2).

I wanna fill that array to load the [[ng2 smart table]](https://akveo.github.io/ng2-smart-table/#/documentation) and if I´m thinking partially well with a properly well-formed array I will fill the table but I don´t know how. Hope anyone can help.

Comment: What do you want to get? A map (object) with `key: value`?

Comment: I want to fill a map, yes, with all the data from the returned objects from firebase

Answer (score 0):

If you want an map (object) with `key: value`, you can easily do this with [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```
const map = snapshots.reduce((map, snapshot) => {
    map[snapshot.key] = snapshot.val();
}, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to the example : https://akveo.github.io/ng2-smart-table/#/examples/using-filters ...

(You can find the source code here: https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table/blob/master/src/app/pages/examples/filter/basic-example-source.component.ts)

... you have to put your data in a JSON object :

```
settings = {
  columns: {
    id: {
      title: 'ID',
      filter: false,
    },
    name: {
      title: 'Full Name',
      filter: false,
    },
    username: {
      title: 'User Name',
      filter: false,
    },
    email: {
      title: 'Email',
      filter: false,
    }
  }
};

data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Leanne Graham',
    username: 'Bret',
    email: 'Sincere@april.biz',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Ervin Howell',
    username: 'Antonette',
    email: 'Shanna@melissa.tv',
  }
];
```

"settings" contain your columns names and "data" must match the columns from "settings".

It would be easier if we knew a bit more of your code (columns of your table + data returned by your service), but I assume something like that would work :

```
data = [];
this.af.database.list('/Documentos', { preserveSnapshot: true })
        .subscribe(snapshots => {
            snapshots.forEach(snapshot => {
                data.push(
                    { [snapshot.key]: snapshot.val() }
                );
            });
        })
```

Please note that this will create a JSON array with only one key/val per row. We do need to know more about your data to give you a propre answer.

Comment: You need to change `{ snapshot.key: snapshot.val() }` to `{ [snapshot.key]: snapshot.val() }` if you want the value of `snapshot.key` to be the key. (I couldn't propose an edit, since the change is less than six characters.)

Comment: Thank you, forgot about that !

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution with a simple Array() x)

```
            this.af.database.list('/Documentos', { preserveSnapshot: true })
            .subscribe(snapshots => {
                snapshots.forEach(snapshot => {
                    let length = todo.documentos.push(snapshot.val()); // documentos is an array in the class
                    todo.source.load(todo.documentos);
                });
            });
```